# issue while populating String into textView

Tags: ios, swift, textview, swift2

[uploaded video (7 sec) for describing my problem](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2ytpt78%3E&s=9#.VpCKK7zRuRs)

i have a textView embed in a tableView cell when we enter something on that `textView` the textview automatically increases its height according to entered content and also cell increases its size for doing this am using this approach:-

```
//tableViewCell

/// Custom setter so we can initialise the height of the text view
var textString: String {
    get {
        return textView?.text ?? ""
    }
    set {
        if let textView = textView {
            textView.text = newValue

            textViewDidChange(textView)
        }
    }
}



    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()



    // Disable scrolling inside the text view so we enlarge to fitted size
    textView?.scrollEnabled = false
    textView?.delegate = self



}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        textView?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textView?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
}

  extension MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {
 func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.max))

    // Resize the cell only when cell's size is changed
    if size.height != newSize.height {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

        if let thisIndexPath = tableView?.indexPathForCell(self) {
            tableView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(thisIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

here everything is fine  but i added a function for Forwarding any content and for this am using this approach :-

```
 forwardNoteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Forward"){ action, index in
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NotesTableViewCell

                if self.searchBar.text == "" {


                    let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
                    let postsObjID = object.objectId!
                    let query = PFQuery(className: "Notes")
                    query.fromLocalDatastore()

                    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(postsObjID) {
                        (objectViewes, error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                        } else {


                            self.forwardObject = object
                            print(self.forwardObject)
                            //object.pinInBackground()

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("forwardNoteSegue", sender: nil)
                self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


                        }
```

i am putting the content into a variable `self.forwardObject` and passing that variable with an segue  `forwardNoteSegue`  after passing  `self.forwardObject` am using that content for filling my tableView (which is a form , consist of textViews and TextFields) but when am doing this my `textView` is not increasing its height according to content which is inside that textView ,

all i want is the textView should increase increase its height when we use "textView.text = copiedContent" same as when we enter anything into the textView manually

please for understanding my problem properly see the uploaded video (link is provided above)

if my question is not understandable than please let me know i'll fix it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually call textViewDidChange when you modify the content of you textview programatically.

This is documented in the UITextviewDelegate's description of the method:

> **The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes to the text. This method is not called in response to
>   programmatically initiated changes.**